# Destructuring props passed to functional component in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

In JavaScript, the destructuring of an object is something common.

```
const foo = {
    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3 
};

const {a, b, c } = foo;
console.log(a)
```

> 1

Is something like this possigle with KotlinJS React?

```
interface FooProps : Props {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
}

val Foo = FC<FooProps> { props -> 
    val(a, b, c) = props
    ...
}
```

This is not working. It gives me

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type FooProps must have a 'component1()' function

Comment: You can’t destructure like that in Kotlin. Did you read the documentation about destructuring declarations? What you can do is use a `with`, `run`, or `apply` scope functions for this kind of thing.

Comment: Given the code in the question, I think it would be much more common simply to refer to `props.a`, `props.b`, etc. in the following code. Is there a particular reason for wanting to split them out to local variables (other than being a familiar pattern from JS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin supports [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html), however they work in a different way than JavaScript.
In particular, you can destructure an object like this:

```
val (property1, property2, property3, ..., propertyN) = object
```

assuming that `object` contains certain methods:

- `operator fun component1()`
- `operator fun component2()`
- ...
- `operator fun componentN()`

Example:

```
class Person(val name: String, val dateOfBirth: LocalDate) {
    operator fun component1(): String = name
    operator fun component2(): LocalDate = dateOfBirth
}

val johnDoe = Person("John", LocalDate.of(1980, JANUARY, 1))

val (name, dob) = johnDoe
println("$name -> $dob") // prints John -> 1980-01-01
```

Use can make use of extension functions to implement this behaviour on classes you don't own. Example:

```
operator fun String.component1(): Int = this.length
operator fun String.component2(): Char = this.first()

val someString = "Hello, world"

val (length, firstChar) = someString
println("$length -> $firstChar") // prints 12 -> H
```